# Checking if there is a certain amount of element in list

Tags: list, lisp

What I mean by my question is:

Lets say there is a list (a b c d)

and I want to make sure there are 4 elements in there before proceeding with my code.

if the list says (a b c)

i want it to return nil, because it's not what I want.

Can anyone help =)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LENGTH function:

```
(when (>= (length list) 4)
  ;; rest of your code
)
```

If you need a method that doesn't scan the entire list just to see if there are N element, you can use this function:

```
(defun length-at-least (list n)
  (cond ((zerop n) t)
        (list (length-at-least (cdr list) (1- n)))
        (t nil)))
```

Then you can do:

```
(when (length-at-least list 4)
  ;; rest of your code
)
```

Comment: Added recursive function to do LENGTH-AT-LEAST

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun has-at-least-elements (n list)
  (do () ((< n 1) t)
    (unless list (return))
    (setq n (1- n) list (cdr list))))

(has-at-least-elements 10 '(1 2 3 4))   ; NIL
(has-at-least-elements 4 '(1 2 3 4))    ; T
```

As a general case this solution will be better, it will also work with cyclic lists and very long lists in the same time.

Comment: I agree. You could also use `(not (null (nthcdr (1- n) list)))`, assuming `n` greater than or equal to 1. EDIT: The original answer by @barmar that was accepted was comparing the result of `length`, so I will leave my upvote in this answer. Moreover, Common Lisp doesn't have to do tail call elimination.

Comment: `(has-at-least-elements 4 '(1 2 3 4 5 . 6) )` is arguably right to return `T`, so what about `(has-at-least-elements 4 '(1 2 . 3) )`?